# SonarQube 6 - new "bugs" appearing in old previously scanned code

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have a daily scan on our Java source code using Sonar. Suddenly yesterday a few hundred new "bugs" appeared in code that hasn't been changed. I would have assumed that the bugs would have already been there after our initial scan and baseline of the project.
Nothing had changed, can anyone come up with a reason why this would happen and if there is anyway to correct it (ideally I need to mark these as already being in my baseline project as we are currently only interested in issues generated in changed code).
I've tried deleting the analysis that detected them, but that didn't help.

Comment: Was the Quality Profile updated?

Comment: No. The rules that flagged up weren't new rules.  Other sources had those violations. The only strange thing that did happen is that during the previous scan another build was started - this meant some of the dependant files could have vanished during a scan.  However this doesn't explain why the violations would flag up in these source files as they should have been there all along.

Comment: Did you update any plugin or SonarQube instance?

Comment: The reason was that because another build had started, the byte code wasn't available.  Therefore all the rules that depend on the byte code, got marked as closed.  Then on the next analysis, once the byte code was available again - the rules were re-added as being new.